# Find an tangent line to $2y=x^3+x\sin y-8$ at $(2,0)$

Tags: calculus

Tangent of$\:2y=x^3+x\sin\:y-8,$ at $\left(2,\:0\right)$

I've been trying for hours but couldn't find the right answer...

When we take derivative of $\sin(y)$ with $\frac{d}{dx}$ do we need to put $\frac{dy}{dx}$ after $\cos(y)$?

Comment: yes, you do need to write dy/dx

Answer (score 1):

You have $ \:2y=x^3+x\sin\:y-8$. Differentiating this:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \ 2y &= \frac{d}{dx} \left (x^3+x\sin\:y-8 \right ) \\
2\frac{dy}{dx} &= 3x^2+ \frac{d}{dx} \left (x\sin y \right ) \\
2\frac{dy}{dx} &= 3x^2+ x\frac{d}{dx}(\sin y) +\sin y \\
2\frac{dy}{dx} &= 3x^2+ x\cos y\frac{dy}{dx} +\sin y \\
\end{align}
$$

Now we can rearrange to make $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the subject:

$$
\begin{align}
2\frac{dy}{dx} - x\cos y\frac{dy}{dx} &= 3x^2  +\sin y \\
\frac{dy}{dx}\left( 2 - x\cos y\right ) &= 3x^2 +\sin y \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{3x^2 +\sin y}{2 - x\cos y} \\
\end{align}
$$

Now what do you notice if we try substituting in $x=2$? Hint: here's a graph of the function

[image]

Comment: I notice that when we plug in what we have the answer will be 12/0 which is an indeterminate form so how come it is possible to get the tangent line?

Comment: @firatozturk What is the gradient of the line $x= 2$? Some tangent lines have an infinite gradient :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm an international student and I've never heard the term gradient could you please be more specific but otherwise it still okay thanks I hope I'll be good. :)

Comment: @firatozturk No worries, I know the struggle. By gradient I mean slope of the tangent line. The indeterminate form of 12/0 implies that the slope of the tangent line is infinite i.e. it is a vertical line. So the tangent line for your question is given by the line $x = 2$ which makes sense if you look at the picture. Does that help? If not let me know, I will clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :$\:2y=x^3+x\sin\:y-8$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$,

$2\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2+x\cos y\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin y$

Then make $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as the subject .

Answer (score 0):

$\:2y=x^3+x\sin\:y-8,$ at $\left(2,\:0\right)$

$\:2\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2+\sin\:y +x\cos\:y\frac{dy}{dx},$ at $\left(2,\:0\right)$

This would give $0*m=12$ after substitution, where $m$ is the slope. Hence $m$ must be infinity. [image: The Plot of the function]

You can see it clearly here.

Thus the tangent will be the line $x=2$

Comment: Did you checked is that function deiffertiable at (2,0)?

Comment: @Ramanujan The function is continuous. Hence, tangent exists. As long as tangent exists, should we care about differentiability? You are right that this function is not differentiable at (2,0). That is the reason why slope is infinity ( a vertical line).